# post request retrofit2 android studio kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

i need for create user . must use request post . im use but this did'nt work and dont have error
. you can see my code

my server :

Allow: POST, OPTIONS

Content-Type: application/json

{
"first_name": "",
"last_name": "",
"email": "",
"username": "",
"password": ""
}

api.kt

```
interface Api {
@POST("users/signup")
@FormUrlEncoded
fun createUser(
    @Field("first_name") fName: String,
    @Field("last_name") lName: String,
    @Field("email") email: String,
    @Field("username") username: String,
    @Field("password") password: String,
): Call<DefaultResponse>
}
```

RetrofitClient.kt

```
object RetrofitClient {

private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor { chain ->
        val original = chain.request()

        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
            .method(original.method(), original.body())

        val request = requestBuilder.build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }.build()

val instance: Api by lazy {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()

    retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
}
}
```

DefaultResponse.kt

```
data class DefaultResponse (val error: Boolean, val message: String)
```

Constants.kt

```
class Constants {

companion object {
    const val BASE_URL = "http://194.62.43.26:1337/api/"
}
}
```

SignUpActivity.kt

```
binding.btnSignup
        .setOnClickListener {

            val username = binding.etUsername.text.toString().trim()
            val password = binding.etPw.text.toString().trim()
            val fName = binding.etFirstName.text.toString().trim()
            val lName = binding.etLastName.text.toString().trim()
            val email = binding.etEmail.text.toString().trim()

            if (username.isEmpty()) {
                binding.etUsername.error = "Password required"
                binding.etUsername.requestFocus()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            if (password.isEmpty()) {
                binding.etPw.error = "Password required"
                binding.etPw.requestFocus()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            RetrofitClient.instance.createUser(fName, lName, email, username, password)
                .enqueue(object : Callback<DefaultResponse> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<DefaultResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<DefaultResponse>,
                        response: Response<DefaultResponse>
                    ) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            response.body()?.message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }

                })
```

Comment: Use request body

Comment: @Gobu CSG i change my api interface to {@POST("users/signup")
    {@FormUrlEncoded}
    fun createPost(@Body user: User): Call<User>} and i have this error = {@Body}parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)

Comment: Why it's multipart!? Are you sending files!?

Comment: Use `@Query` instead of `@Field`.

Comment: @UndefinedBug1.0 i use '@Query' but i have error Form-encoded method must contain at least one '@Field'.

Comment: @GobuCSG i send string you can see my file in github https://github.com/Saeedmoeen/App

Comment: Remove formurlencoded and post it as body.... Query parms won't work @SaeedMoeen

Comment: @GobuCSG i have this error '@Field' parameters can only be used with form encoding..... you see my code in github ?

Comment: Yeah remove formurlenocoded and field annotations as well modify @Body pass your data class will work

Comment: @GobuCSG i change but dont work

Comment: Check your server side person

Comment: @GobuCSG server is work good .... i think my code have mistake... because i can create user with postman

Comment: Can you share postman request screenshot

Comment: @GobuCSG sure https://pasteboard.co/NW2SIy7GddAQ.png

Comment: @GobuCSG i have status code 403 in my app

Comment: @GobuCSG i think my mistake here https://pasteboard.co/TomWZoFvpBsH.png how can i fix this ?

Comment: 403 server side fix.. reach out them

Comment: Maybe try like this

@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@POST("users/signup")
@FormUrlEncoded

Comment: @GobuCSG don't work

Comment: Reach out them.